# Oracle TO_CHAR function does not convert minutes correctly (Georgian to Persian)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to convert Gregorian date to Persian date with `TO_CHAR` function. It changes minutes.

Why is that? [Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa68d.png).

```
 SELECT MEASURE_DATETIME,
       TO_CHAR(MEASURE_DATETIME,
               'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM:SS',
               'NLS_CALENDAR=''PERSIAN''') PERSIAN_DATE
  FROM MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210) the placeholder for minutes is `MI` not `MM`

```
TO_CHAR(MEASURE_DATETIME,
               'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS',
               'NLS_CALENDAR=''PERSIAN''') PERSIAN_DATE
```

Answer (score -1):

'MM' is months.  Use 'MI' for minutes.

Comment: What does your answer add to the existing one?

Comment: @mustaccio Both answers were posted less than a minute apart, they were likely just both posting at the same time.